# Excel VBA DoWhile Loop - how to return list of items with each loop?

Tags: vba

I am pulling entries from a purchase order template in 1 worksheet into a database worksheet that will record all purchase order date in the same Excel workbook.  The SKU's ordered on the order template tab will often exceed 1, and will differ from one another.  Wondering how to pull the differing SKU No.'s into the database tab with an edit to VBA code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OrderDate As String, PONumber As String, Vendor As String, ShipTo As String, SKU As String
    Worksheets("Order Form 1").Select
    OrderDate = Range("B3")
    PONumber = Range("D3")
    Vendor = Range("B7")
    ShipTo = Range("D7")
    SKU = Range("F3")
    R = 3
    Do While Cells(R, 6) <> ""
        Worksheets("Database").Select
        Worksheets("Database").Range("A1").Select
        If Worksheets("Database").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Database").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = OrderDate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = PONumber
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Vendor
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = ShipTo
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = SKU
        Worksheets("Order Form 1").Select
        R = R + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Essentially there are 2 workbooks? You have to ditch `.Select` and the generic `Range(...)`, `ActiveCell` to ensure less chance of error. One way to reach your goal is to create 2 Workbook/Worksheet variables, use Offset/create 2 Long variables to store the rows you are processing/writing.

Comment: 1) Be clear on where your multiple SKUs are stored in the order sheet 2) Use vbNullstring rather than "" 3) Make sure you are not overwriting existing values; you will want find the next available row to write to.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that all of the .Selects and ActiveCell references are ugly. But, in trying to leave as much of your code alone as possible, here is one method:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OrderDate As String, PONumber As String, Vendor As String, ShipTo As String, SKU As String
    Dim R As Long, LastRow As Long
    Worksheets("Order Form 1").Select
    OrderDate = Range("B3")
    PONumber = Range("D3")
    Vendor = Range("B7")
    ShipTo = Range("D7")
    LastRow = Worksheets("Order Form 1").Cells(Worksheets("Order Form 1").Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    For R = 3 To LastRow
        SKU = Range("F" & R).Value
        Worksheets("Database").Select
        Worksheets("Database").Range("A1").Select
        If Worksheets("Database").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
            Worksheets("Database").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = OrderDate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = PONumber
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Vendor
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = ShipTo
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = SKU
        Worksheets("Order Form 1").Select
    Next R
End Sub
```

And here is an effort to eliminate .Selects and ActiveCell references:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OrderDate As String, PONumber As String, Vendor As String, ShipTo As String, SKU As String
    Dim R As Long, LastSKURow As Long, NextDBRow As Long, OFrm As Worksheet, DB As Worksheet
    Set OFrm = Worksheets("Order Form 1")
    Set DB = Worksheets("Database")
    OrderDate = OFrm.Range("B3")
    PONumber = OFrm.Range("D3")
    Vendor = OFrm.Range("B7")
    ShipTo = OFrm.Range("D7")
    LastSKURow = OFrm.Cells(OFrm.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    For R = 3 To LastSKURow
        SKU = OFrm.Range("F" & R).Value
        NextDBRow = DB.Cells(DB.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        DB.Range("A" & NextDBRow).Value = OrderDate
        DB.Range("B" & NextDBRow).Value = PONumber
        DB.Range("C" & NextDBRow).Value = Vendor
        DB.Range("D" & NextDBRow).Value = ShipTo
        DB.Range("E" & NextDBRow).Value = SKU
    Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: TLEMaster, thank you- this worked like a charm - the condensed version, that is.  Wondering, too, if you can build in a re-set instruction to clear out the data from the order form after the order has been placed?  Also looking to auto-save in pdf format with the click of the command button, too.  I am impressed with your skill - and very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Eric, Glad this is working for you. Regarding your other requests, I suggest using the Macro Recorder to help you out. Record one where you right-click and select "Clear Contents".  Record another where you Save As a PDF. That will produce some code to get you started.

Comment: TLEMaster,  Can I have you look at the code that was produced and have you let me know where the disconnect is?  It states there is a bug that I am uanble to identify.  Thank you!